# how to save intermediate variable calculated in objective function being minimized using scipy.optimize.minimize

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I'm doing a PDE-constrained optimization problem where I'm trying to optimize the control variable `C` so that the dependent variable in the PDE `dy(t,x)/dt = f(y,t)` can match the target profile `y_opt` as closely as possible. I have something like this:

```
def PDE(t,C):
    # codes for solving the decretized PDE using method of lines
    return dy/dt

def objective(C,y_opt):
    # objective function to be minimized
    sol = scipy.integrate.solve_ivp(lambda t: PDE(t,C), (0,t_stop), y_initial, method='BDF')
    y_end = sol.y[:,-1]

    cost = np.sum((y_end-y_opt)**2)
    return cost

res = scipy.optimize.minimize(lambda C: objective(C,y_opt), C_guess, method='CG', options={'return_all':True})
```

The above code works for my problem, and I can see the current best solution of `C` at each iteration by setting `return_all':True` inside `scipy.optimize.minimize`. However, I also want to know the variable `y_end` at each iteration. Currently, I have to solve `PDE` using the output `C` at each iteration to get the corresponding `y_end`, but since it is already calculated during the optimization function call, I wonder how I can save the calculated `y_end` at each iteration directly.